# How do I deserialize json with nested breakslashes?

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization

I have a piece of json, but when I go to deserialize it, it won't map correctly to an object in C#.

Ex:

```
    "location": {
            "raw": "{\"address1\":\"1234 Fake Street\",\"address2\":null,\"city\":\"Madison\",\"state\":\"WI\",\"zip\":\"12345\",\"country\":\"US\"}"
        },
```

I'm using restSharp to make the api call and Newtonsoft.Json

var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

I've tried the following and failed:

1. Parsing the json
2. Replacing the backslashes
3. Serializing, then deserializing again
4. JavascriptSerializer

Is there anyway to deserialize a string into an object with the backslashes there?

Comment: I don't see any backslashes in your example. Please provide a sample which actually illustrates the problem.

Comment: I updated it, without the code block it auto formatted it correctly, now its showing

Comment: Post also your C# class

Comment: The backslashes are standard JSON to escape double-quotes. JSON de-serialization will take that and return the string `{"address1":"1234 Fake Street", ...`. If you want the backslashes after de-serializing w/JSON, you'll have to put them back in. Or investigate how in JSON to escape backslashes at creation time.